# Firebase using JS - Struggling to update value if exists or add if it doesnt

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Bit confused why this won't work.

```
      const person = {};
      person[this.name] = 0;

      const personQuery = `person/${this.name}`;
      firebase.child(personQuery).on('value', (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          // Update
          console.log('exists');
        } else {
          console.log('creating');
          firebase.child('person').set(person, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
          });
        }
        this.name = '';
      });
```

My data looks like this if I get rid of the updating logic and just have the setting logic:

Bill: 0,

John: 0,

Beth: 0

etc

If the record exists it doesn't have a problem (since I'm not even doing the update yet) but if it doesn't it just goes into a crazy loop and I end up with a single value in my table at the end.

I think I'm misinterpreting how to structure my data.

I basically want to make a super simple app with a key value pair of people, each person has 1 single number and if the person already exists then increment the value by one.

Can someone help me out with understanding how to create the structure and query for it to make the updates?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once). Since you only want to check if the person node currently exists and don't want to keep synchronizing it. So:

```
  firebase.child(personQuery).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      // Update
      console.log('exists');
    } else {
      console.log('creating');
      firebase.child('person').set(person, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
      });
    }
    this.name = '';
  });
```

But in general this sort of scenario calls for [use of a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). With a transaction you get the current value and specify the new value atomically. This removes a race condition that exists in your current code.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'm away from the code now but I'll try tomorrow and report back, thanks very much